# How can I delete unwanted elements from this JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following response from an API containing a JSON array and I am trying to remove all elements except for title, column, and searchSourceJSON:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Integration-Enabled",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Integration - Enabled",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "_source"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "timestamp",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"value\":\"Media Integration\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Integration\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Action\",\"value\":\"Enable\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Action\":{\"query\":\"Enable\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}],\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Import-True",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Import - True",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "FormFactor",
                "_type",
                "Identity"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "_type",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"disabled\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"negate\":false,\"value\":\"Media Import\"},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Import\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Successful\",\"value\":\"True\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Successful\":{\"query\":\"True\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}]}"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Could someone help me figure out how to delete the unwanted elements from this JSON document using JavaScript?

EDIT: Answered, thank you everyone for the great information!

Comment: You could just create a new js object and take the values from the properties you wish to keep

Comment: If you're only interested in just those couple properties, why both stripping away things from this big data structure when you can just make a new object with the properties you're looking for? `hits.map(hit=> ({title: hit._source.title, /* ... */}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Transverse all the result (which tend to be costly) using a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) approach.
- Or as it seems to be a request to Elastic Search to filter out the response send by ES. Therefore, less network traffic and you could avoid the need to clean up the data.

You can add a [filter path on your query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) this way:

`_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Yep, this is a response from Elasticsearch. Thank you for exposing me to filter path! I really should go through all the documentation...

Answer (score 3):

One low effort way is to use `Array#Map` and then select only the elements you want.

```js
var hits = [
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Integration-Enabled",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Integration - Enabled",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "_source"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "timestamp",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"value\":\"Media Integration\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Integration\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Action\",\"value\":\"Enable\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Action\":{\"query\":\"Enable\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}],\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Import-True",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Import - True",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "FormFactor",
                "_type",
                "Identity"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "_type",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"disabled\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"negate\":false,\"value\":\"Media Import\"},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Import\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Successful\",\"value\":\"True\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Successful\":{\"query\":\"True\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}]}"
            }
        }
    }
]

var filtered = hits.map(function(hit){
  return { title : hit._source.title, searchSourceJSON : hit._source.exampleSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON, columns : hit._source.columns}
})

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON, and then map to create a new array containing objects with just the properties you need :

```
const data = JSON.parse(yourJSON);
const hits = data.hits.map(hit => ({
    title: hit._source.title,
    searchSourceJSON: hit._source.exampleSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON
});
```

Comment: It appears to already be an Object rather than a string. I don't think JSON.parse is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=(function(){//IIFE to enshure garbage collection
  var hits=[...];//your data
  return hits.map(hit=>{hit["_source"].title,hit["_source"].colums,hit.exampleSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON});
});
```

This deletes all properties (garbage collects them) except the wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Integration-Enabled",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Integration - Enabled",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "_source"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "timestamp",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"value\":\"Media Integration\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Integration\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Action\",\"value\":\"Enable\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Action\":{\"query\":\"Enable\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}],\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": ".example_demo",
        "_type": "search",
        "_id": "demo-Media-Import-True",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "demo Media Import - True",
            "description": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "columns": [
                "FormFactor",
                "_type",
                "Identity"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "_type",
                "asc"
            ],
            "version": 1,
            "exampleSavedObjectMeta": {
                "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"highlight\":{\"pre_tags\":[\"@example-highlighted-field@\"],\"post_tags\":[\"@/example-highlighted-field@\"],\"fields\":{\"*\":{}},\"fragment_size\":2147483647},\"filter\":[{\"meta\":{\"disabled\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"_type\",\"negate\":false,\"value\":\"Media Import\"},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"_type\":{\"query\":\"Media Import\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}},{\"meta\":{\"negate\":false,\"index\":\"[demo-]YYYY.MM\",\"key\":\"Successful\",\"value\":\"True\",\"disabled\":false},\"query\":{\"match\":{\"Successful\":{\"query\":\"True\",\"type\":\"phrase\"}}}}]}"
            }
        }
    }
];

var res = jsonObj.map(function(item) {
  return { 
           "title": item._source.title, 
           "columns": item._source.columns,
           "searchSourceJSON": item._source.exampleSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON
         };
});

console.log(res);
```